# PHP 5.6.40 Windows, FTPS connection failed (SSL/TLS handshake failed)

Tags: php, ssl, tls1.2, ftps

I'm trying to connect to a FTPS Server with PHP 5.6.40 on Windows.

I know that I need to recompile PHP to include OpenSSL and FTP in the PHP bundle and that's what I did.

The `ftp_ssl_connect` function is here now but I get a SSL/TLS handshake error.

When I try to connect to a public FTPS Server, I encounter the following error:

> ```
> Warning: ftp_login(): SSL/TLS handshake failed in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php on line 13
> PHP Warning: ftp_login(): SSL/TLS handshake failed in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php on line 13 PHP Warning: ftp_login(): AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation. in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php on line 13
> Warning: ftp_login(): AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation. in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php on line 13
> ```

This script runs great on PHP 5.6.40/Linux.

I tried too, to have the same result with cURL commands, It's great on Windows and Linux, but I would really like to use PHP's FTP commands.

Any idea ?

```php
<?php

$ftpserver = "test.rebex.net";
$user = "demo";
$mdp = "password";

$connectionId = ftp_ssl_connect($ftpserver);

$login_result = ftp_login($connectionId, $user, $mdp);
ftp_pasv($connectionId, true);
$pasv_result = ftp_pasv($connectionId, true);

if ($pasv_result)
    echo "ok";
else
    echo "nok";
print_r( ftp_nlist($connectionId,'.'));
```